# How can I assign the current process to a newly created job object?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I can't seem to use the [AssignProcessToJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681949(VS.85).aspx) function to assign the current process to a job object handle given by [CreateJobObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682409(VS.85).aspx). This has been asked a few times already on StackOverflow, but so far none of the solutions (which usually boil down to embedding an UAC manifest) seem to work for me.

I'm using MSVC9 on Windows 7 for this. Here's the source code for my sample application and a small manifest I'm embedding (which supposedly fixes the problem - but not for me):

My sample application (`main.cpp`):

```
#include <windows.h>

static void dumpLastError()
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );
    OutputDebugStringA( (LPTSTR)lpMsgBuf );

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE job = CreateJobObjectA( NULL, "demo job 123" );
    if ( !job ) {
        OutputDebugStringA( "CreateJobObject failed" );
        dumpLastError();
        return 1;
    }

    if ( !AssignProcessToJobObject( job, GetCurrentProcess() ) ) {
        OutputDebugStringA( "AssignProcessToJobObject failed" );
        dumpLastError();
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The UAC manifest (`main.exe.manifest`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
   <ms_asmv3:trustInfo xmlns:ms_asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <ms_asmv3:security>
         <ms_asmv3:requestedPrivileges>
            <ms_asmv3:requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/>
         </ms_asmv3:requestedPrivileges>
      </ms_asmv3:security>
   </ms_asmv3:trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

I build this sample by running

```
cl main.cpp
mt -manifest main.exe.manifest -outputresource:main.exe;1
```

Unfortunately, running my `main.exe` sample after these steps still yields an 'Access denied' error in debug output when attempting the `AssignProcessToJobObject` call. Does anybody know why that is?

Comment: Are you using cygwin by any chance? Or are your build/run commands in a cmd window?

Comment: @Ryan Calhoun: No, I'm not using Cygwin but I'm using PyCmd (a simple cmd.exe replacement). That's an interesting question! I just tried it from within cmd.exe and now it seems to work! Odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed a number of discussions at one point relating to job objects and UAC manifests. The only piece of information that helped me around the same problem that you're having was that this security feature (introduced in Vista) is apparently not enforced when run from a cmd.

I assume you're launching PyCmd from the start menu. Try launching it from cmd, and I'll bet the problem will go away there too.

What I ended up doing (to run mintty with cygwin) was to make a mintty.bat which said

```
start mintty.exe
```

and then a shortcut to mintty.bat which had a property set to run 'minimized' (I forget the exact wording). This allows the shell I wanted to be launched from the start menu and still work as if it had been launched from cmd.exe.

As a side-note, I'd love it if someone would come along and actually explain the problem at a build-level, and how to fix it.

Comment: I've got no idea about the UAC issue or why cmd makes a difference, but you can cut out the .bat file by setting your shortcut target like so: `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c start C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -`

Comment: Thank you, I had problem with this subject in Windows 7, your note help me a lot.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but I was recently having the exact same problem.
As suggested I was using the command-line workaround until a couple of minutes ago I found [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2009/07/10/how-to-work-around-program-compatibility-assistant-pca-jobobjects-interfering-with-your-jobobjects.aspx).

Since I was creating the process, I just followed the instructions on the article adding CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB to the process creation flags:

```
CreateProcess(szPath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)
```

with

```
CreateProcess(szPath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)
```

I tested and it works as expected, the process gets assigned to the job, no UAC manifest, no command-line.

Hope it helps you or anyone else having this problem.

Comment: +1 Ah, very interesting! I knew about `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB`, but I didn't explicitely check whether I'm setting it in all cases. Thanks for taking the time to share this. :-)

Comment: The relevant documentation is here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681949(v=vs.85).aspx): If the process is being monitored by the Program Compatibility Assistant (PCA), it is placed into a compatibility job. Therefore, the process must be created using CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB before it can be placed in another job. Alternatively, you can embed an application manifest that specifies a User Account Control (UAC) level in your application and PCA will not add the process to the compatibility job.

Comment: That's quite a find. Never would have thought of a newly created process being _immediately_ added to some job, which I did not create myself, obviously by hooking CreateProcess. Good to know!